# Printing a domain that does not exist

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way where I can print out that the domain does not exist instead of giving me an error like this

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.enroll.connect.web.co.id', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4f558003d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

This is the code that i use to check whether the domain exist or not

```
request = requests.get('https://www.enroll.connect.web.co.id')
if request.status_code == 200:
    print('Web site exists')
else:
    print('Web site does not exist')
```

The logic should've been if the status is 200 then that means the website existed, but if it's not 200 it should've print out that the website does not exist.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Exception Handling`:
**code:**

```
import requests

try:
    request = requests.get('https://www.enroll.connect.web.co.id')
    if request.status_code == 200:
        print('Web site exists')
except :       
    print('Web site does not exist')
```

Comment: and if it's helpful to get the error message `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: @shawncaza exactly and + raise your own error using `raise`.

Comment: Is there a reason on why i should use try and except in the code? Is it to make sure that if the website doesn't exist it would go to the except? @Mehmaam

Comment: its not specifc to your code, you have any code snippets where you have a doubt if it can face an error and system crash then use try block to tackle it and after that you can know error using except block.

Comment: There are else and finally block to you must learn about `Exception Handling`.

Comment: This prints nothing if the code is not exactly 200 (e.g. auth required)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I prefer to use an exception and just bypass it

```
import requests
try:
    request = requests.get('https://www.akjsbdas,la.zxcvksam')
    if request.status_code == 200:
        print('Web site exists')
except:
    print('Web site does not exist')
```

or to improve the code, you can specify the exception error and make it even better:

```
import requests
url= 'testashsbfdckasjd.com'
try:
    get = requests.get(url)
    if get.status_code == 200:
        print(f"{url}: does exists")
    else:
        print(f"{url}: does not exist, status_code: {get.status_code}")

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as ReqExcp:
    raise SystemExit(f"{url}: does not exist \nError: {ReqExcp}")
```

Comment: if i use that code line `except: print('Web site does not exist')` for a bunch of amount of website where i give all of the possible url on an array into a variable, wouldn't it going to print out `website does not exist` to the total amount of url that i can possibly generate? is there a different alternative instead of using try and except @DrunkLeen

Comment: Unfortunately the best way to handle it is using exception.
But you have to be careful with requests and use the URL in "http/https : // domain" style or improve it to that style